# ES6 Uncaught TypeError: xxx is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a module entry point init.js as follows,

```
import $ from 'platform!jquery';
import angular from 'platform!angular';
import ngRoute from 'platform!angular-route';
import kendo from 'platform!kendo-ui';
import DemoModuleMain from './scripts/app.min';

export function render(containerElement, startingRoute, platform) 
{
$.ajax({
    url: platform.proxyUrl('/content/Default.aspx'),
    success: function (template) {
        containerElement.innerHTML = template;
        DemoModuleMain.main(platform);
        angular.bootstrap(containerElement, ['myApp']);
    },
    error: function (a, b, error) {
        containerElement.innerHTML = "Error: " + error;
    }
})
}
```

Then the app.min.js file

```
import UserService from './services/UserService';
import UserController from './controllers/UserController';
import {UpperFilter, LowerFilter} from './filters/TextFilters';
import ClientInformation from './directives/ClientInfo';
import ocLazyLoad from '../libs/ocLazyLoad.min.js';

class DemoModuleMain
{
 constructor(){
    alert('init');
 }

 main(platform){
    this._platform = platform;
    var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','oc.lazyLoad']);
    mainApp.controller('UserController', UserController)
                 .service('UserService', UserService)
                 .filter('upper', UpperFilter)
                 .filter('lower', LowerFilter)
                 .directive('clientInfo', ClientInformation);

    mainApp.paths = {
        baseurl: 'extModReq/ngmod/',
        apiurl:'extModReq/ngmod/content/Default.aspx'
    };

    mainApp.constant('BASE_URL', mainApp.paths.baseurl);
    mainApp.constant('API_URL', mainApp.paths.apiurl);

    mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider, BASE_URL) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/Client/:param', {
                    templateUrl: BASE_URL+'content/Client.html'
                })          
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
    });
  }
}

export default DemoModuleMain;
```

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: DemoModuleMain.main is not a function" at DemoModuleMain.main(platform); What could be the problem?

Comment: Uh, `DemoModuleMain.main` *is* not a function, because `DemoModuleMain` is a class and it would be `DemoModuleMain.prototype.main`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `DemoModuleMain.main()` then `main` needs to be static method. Try this

```
class DemoModuleMain {

  constructor() {
    alert('init');
  }

  static main(platform) { }

}
```

However, in this case you can't use `this` inside of it (because there is no instance). So you should instantiate `DemoModuleMain` instance and then call its `main` method:

```
var demo = new DemoModuleMain()
demo.main(platform)
```

Comment: Given that `this` is not really used anywhere, it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `main` method then you'll need to instantiate your class.

```
const demo = new DemoModuleMain();
demo.main(platform);
```

Or just export the method directly.

```
export function main(platform){
  // ...
}
```

Then use it with a named import.

```
import { main } from './scripts/app.min';
main(platform);
```

Comment: I tried all of them, but the real issue was with the JSPM configuration option in Gulpfile, got it resolved by setting the build format.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the `main` method on the class itself, as if it was static. You would need to instantiate your class, or add the `static` keyword to the method. But neither of those options really makes sense. You shouldn't use a `class` here at all. Just export a function, like in your `init` module:

```
…
export function main(platform) {
    var mainApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','oc.lazyLoad']);
    …
}
```

```
…
import * as DemoModuleMain from './scripts/app.min';
…
DemoModuleMain.main(platform);
```